# clarification on db2 optimiser - Runstas

Tags: db2, query-optimization

I had a complicated table which has only 7 columns but in production it will have many rows say more than 100,000 rows..

so for this i execute RUNSTATS for two columns one is PK and another is FK..

```
RUNSTATS ON TABLE WEBSS.P0029_LOCATION  WITH DISTRIBUTION ON COLUMNS (LOC_ID, OUTLET_ID);
```

after this when i run

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.COLDIST WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'WEBSS' AND TABNAME = 'P0029_LOCATION'
```

In result i had 60 rows.. 30 rows each for two columns..
in that i had type is Q and F.. Quantile and Frequeency..

But i need little more input on this.. on what basis they(Q and F) are defined..
on what basis do we need to optimise.

Please pour your suggestions.

Comment: Never looked that far into this, but I would assume frequency is how often certain values occurred (which is key to building indices).  If you're just getting into doing optimization, try reading a lot, but take a higher-level view, too; the various explain-plan utilities will recommend certain indices to try.  And 100,000 rows is piddling change for an enterprise - I'm sitting on multiple tables with 100,000,000+.  Heck, even on consumer-grade hardware that should be no problem (although it's probably going to want indices at that point regardless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two type of column statistics on DB2, simple ones where you just get the column cardinality and the number of nulls, and distribution stats as you have collected above.

I found simple statistics are better for most applications unless you do literal searches on highly skewed data.

If you have indexes defined on you PKs and FKs you get simple stats with

```
RUNSTATS ON MYTABLE ON KEY COLUMNS
```

or

```
RUNSTATS ON MYTABLE ON ALL COLUMNS
```

The quantiles are histogram data, and you get by default I think 20 histogram values for each, and the F are the most popular values in your column, and I then you get 10 by default.   You don't need distributions on a PK, as it's unique, and it's unlikely you need them on an FK as well.  Stick to the simple ones first.